# Clases (css) de Pickadate.js en Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, datepicker

Buenas comunidad, tengo un incoveniente con pickdate requiero quitar una clases de css del calendario. Las clases que deseo deshabilitar son:
1) .picker__day--highlighted
2).picker__day.picker__day--today
Con el fin de quitar el color (verde) al dia de hoy.

[image: El día (9) requiero que quede sin color]

Answer (score 0):

En vez de eliminar las clases, lo que podrías hacer es deshabilitar el color verde editando el estilo css de la clase.

O bien con **inherit**

```
.picker__day.picker__day--today {
    color: inherit;
}
```

o cualquier otro color deseado

```
.picker__day.picker__day--today {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```